# Homeomorphism of a map

Tags: general-topology

Consider $[0,2\pi)\subset\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb S^1=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2~|~x^2+y^2=1\}$.  Show that

$$f:[0,2\pi)\to\Bbb S^1:x\mapsto(\cos(x),\sin(x))$$

is a continuous bijection but not a homeomorphism.

By definition I need to show that $f$ is continuous and bijective but the inverse is not continuous.  However, I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** The image of a connected set under a continuous map is connected.

Comment: this would require me to assume that $f$ is continuous, however, isn't that something we need to show

Comment: Demonstrating the continuity of $f$ itself is straightforward; the continuity of the inverse is a bit trickier, which is where this hint comes in handy.

Comment: could you explain how i would show, $f$ is continuous and bijective?

Comment: Continuity is because the component functions are continuous. Bijectivity can be proven directly (if $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$, then show $x_1=x_2$ and show that given $y\in S^1$, there exists $t\in[0,2\pi)$ so that $f(t)=y$).

Comment: ahhh makes sense, ... then to show $f$ inverse is not continuous we show the map isnt connected as its not closed and bounded

Comment: You might check your definitions; it appears you are thinking of compactness rather than connectedness (I think you can adapt the proof I had in mind to work with compactness as well, but it will require more effort).

Comment: ohhhh my bad yes that is for compactness ... would i prove it by showing the image can be written as the union of disjoint subsets? or show it is not path connected? and this implies that it is not connected?